# What is the right syntax for updating table on Redshift? (code example)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to create a scheduled query to update an existing table on Redshift daily.

The idea is that I want to add daily new rows with events that happen with unique key1 and key2. Also, I want to update rows in the last week that had updates in value1, value2 or value3, but I want to insert these values only if in the original prod table they were null (and so I cannot delete rows and insert them again for that key1 and key2). And I want to leave rows that happened more than a week ago untouched.

I'm missing the right syntax probably because the code below doesn't work. Query for temp table works fine. Could you please advise on what I'm missing here?

Redshift documentation with example is here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/merge-specify-a-column-list.html

```
create temp table [temp_table_name] as 

[SELECT * FROM temp_table_name]; 
 
begin transaction;
    
update [prod_table_name] 
set value1 = NVL(value1, temp_table_name.value1),
value2 = NVL(value2, temp_table_name.value1),
value3 = NVL(value3, temp_table_name.value1)
from [temp_table_name]
where key1 = temp_table_name.key1
and key2 = temp_table_name.key2
and key3 = temp_table_name.key3
and key4 = temp_table_name.key4;

insert into [prod_table_name]
select *
from [temp_table_name]
where value1 <> temp_table_name.value1 
and value2 <> temp_table_name.value2;
     
end transaction;
```

I run into all different kinds of errors and cannot find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is the ambiguity of "key1" and "value1".  I think you need to specify the target table by name in the WHERE clauses.  Like this:

```
where prod_table_name.key1 = temp_table_name.key1
```

and:

```
where prod_table_name.value1 <> temp_table_name.value1
```